# Incorrect Geometry When Enabling Alpha Blending

Tags: c#, 3d, alphablending, slimdx, alpha-transparency

I have a test application with enabled transparency achieved through alpha blending. The application is built in C# using SlimDX. However, on one of my objects that has alpha blending applied, I am getting a strange 'missing triangle' effect (see below).

[image]

The object is almost a cylinder.

I wondered if anyone more experienced in 3D computer graphics and/or the use of alpha blending might be able to point me in the right direction so I might understand this result - and hopefully remove it.

**EDIT**

I have tried to use an order independent blending shader and I get the same result. It would appear as though the pixels/fragments are being discarded due to failing the depth test. This does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select a blending function that is order independent or try to sort you triangles along the view axis (which is impossible). See [why](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Alpha_blending_and_the_Z_buffer) here.

*EDIT:*

*The problem is that the Z buffer prevents OpenGL from drawing pixels that are behind things that have already been drawn. Generally, that's pretty convenient, but when the thing in front is translucent, you need to see the things that are behind it.*

To get a correct looking geometry:

- Put your depth buffer to read only mode.
- Select an order independent blending function.

Comment: Impossible you say? Have you never used a PowerVR graphics card?

Comment: Impossible on common hardware. [PowerVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerVR#Technology) graphic cards store a triangle list per fragment.

Comment: The blending works fine on other models that I am rendering, it is just this one. I've been debugging it in PIX and it states that the pixels have been discarded as they have failed the depth test.

Comment: I've been debugging some more in PIX (before making changes) and I've stopped getting the depth test failure message (not sure why). I've also just found that setting SrcBlend to SrcAlpha (as I had it) and DestBlend to DestAlpha (it was InvSrcAlpha), and making the ZBuffer read-only removes my missing fragment issue.

I do not understand this though and I don't think it works as a perfect solution as I now have rather bright blending in places.

Comment: I finally (more or less) managed to find a solution to the problem I was having. At the time of posting this question, I didn't fully understand the problem. However, thanks to this post and a selection of articles and forums since, I have learned that you were right in highlighting that the triangles were in the wrong order. As such, implementing an order independent transparency algorithm has been the only possibly solution. Thanks for the answer.